# Calculate code metrics for VS2015 C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-analysis, metrics

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and I'm trying to make use of its integrated "calculate code metrics" functionality on a simple C++ project. It fails with this error

> Message: The project target file 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GuessTheNumber\Debug\GuessTheNumber.exe' contains no managed code.

Here are the steps I took. I created a Visual C++ "Win32 Console Application", ticked "Empty project" and "Security Development Lifecycle (SDL) checks".

Then, through the IDE, I added a new "main.cpp" file in the Sources folder.
I wrote a simple program with just a main method, that compiles runs fine.

If I try to calculate metrics on the solution or on the file, I get the error pasted above.

What did I do wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Was your C++ project created as a managed .NET? "Win32 Console Application " = no, it wasn't. So... there you go.

Comment: It surprises me that VS, knowing I can't use that functionality with that kind of project, still shows me the option and then throws an error when I try to use it. Besides, why should it only work with managed code, which is potentially more complex?

Comment: That added complexity you noted likely is the sauce that makes it work. meta-data is the main-course in .NET.

Comment: Like that "culinary" explanation :D Still, it would be nice if VS didn't show me functionalities I can't use...

Comment: Yeah, they do the same thing for Analytics if you didn't shell out the full bore price for the enterprise of architect versions. I know the feeling.

Comment: Does the "enterprise" version compute metrics for non-managed C++ programs?

Comment: @Agostino: If you switch your C++ program to "managed", do you get metrics? (That is, does it produce metrics for C++ code under any circumstances?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, the code metrics just work for C# projects. The error message states the same. Your exe does not contain managed code.

Comment: Any official plugin/workaround for making it work with C++? Or widely-used free solutions for this particular scenario?